# Android Studio não reconhece dispositivo USB

Tags: android-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um dispositivo Motorola MOTO E 2ª Geração, que consigo instalar aplicações por meio da depuração USB em outros computadores, porém, neste PC em específico o Android Studio não aparece meu dispositivo. 
No computador aparece meu celular conectado, e no celular está ativado o modo Programador e tudo mais.

Comment: Baixe o driver aqui:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers
Foi o que funcionou pra mim.

Answer (score 1):

1º Verifique se seu celular esta em modo de desenvolvedor e acionado a depuração USB

2º Verifique se todos os drivers do celular estão instalados no computador (acontece as vezes de ter de baixar algum driver no site da fabricante)

3º verifique se o ADB esta na pasta do SDK do android.

Espero que esses passos te ajude

Comment: Daniel, os Passos 1 e 2 estão conferes. Agora queria uma ajuda para verificar o ADB na pasta SDK. Como posso saber se o ADB está la ?

Comment: Acesse o diretorio do SDK, a pasta \platform-tools lá terá o adb.exe

abra o cmd e acesse essa pasta

com o cmd acessando a pasta coloque o seguinte comando adb devices

ele deve listar seu device se estiver conectado

Comment: *"Verifique se todos os drivers do celular estão instalados no computador"*. @DanielSaraiva, tem alguma maneira de verificar se todos os drivers foram instalados?